# Geant4 error while building INSTALL from the Geant4.sln

Tags: c++, geant4

i have a big problem when installing geant4 in windows 7 64 bit with vs2010 and geant4 4.10
With cmake everything goes fine but then when it come to build the INSTALL packagese in the Geant4.sln when it comes to about the 3000 line it throws an error:

[image: Error]

What could be causing this error?
EDIT:
i've changed in the cmake_install this

```
 execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "$ENV{DESTDIR}C:/Program Files/Geant4/lib/Geant4-10.0.1")
```

with this:

```
  execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory $ENV{DESTDIR} "C:/Program Files/Geant4/lib/Geant4-10.0.1")
```

The error has changed in some ways,not in the form but now it appear just after the compiler start to build the INSTALL package.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with "Visual Studio version 2012" and it worked...
try this instead of vs2010.
I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're recommending the use of a 10-year-old version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I had this problem... someone suggest me to use vs 2012 and it worked for me.